# How can i Show the images in browser with mixit plugin where image link is coming from DB but the image is not showing in an Asp.net MVC application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mixitup

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AdSite.Models.Album>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<button class="filter btn btn-primary" data-filter=".category-1">Category 1</button>
<button class="filter btn btn-success" data-filter=".category-2">Category 2</button>
<button class="sort btn btn-default" data-sort="my-order:asc">Ascending Order</button>
<button class="sort btn btn-primary" data-sort="my-order:desc">Descending Order</button>
<button class="filter btn btn-success" data-filter=".all">All</button>

<div id="Container">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <div class=" mix category-1 all" data-my-order="@item.Id">
        <img alt="" src="@item.ProductTitle" />
    </div>
     }
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/App/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#Container').mixItUp();
        });
    </script>
 }
```

My Controller action:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var db = new AlbumContext();
            return View(db.Albums.ToList());
        }
```

My model:

```
public class Album
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }`

        public string ProductTitle { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
```

So, This are my codes. I need to show  images by the mixit plugin used here on browser. I've used here a view referencing an `Album model` and a `foreach loop` is used for taking the `image`link given in the `ProductTitle` property. Also i uploaded an `image` in the `Content` folder of the project. When i'm running the code, the image link is showing in the browser's source code but the image is not showing. How can i fix it? Anyone's help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: how the url looks like in the db, is it relative path?

Comment: Hello @EhsanSajjad i'm using EF code first model. and the url of the image look like this                      `"~/Content/image/2.jpg"`

Comment: Use Url.Content like <img src="@Url.Content(Model.ProductTitle)" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by using:

`<img src="@Url.Content(@Model.ProductTitle)" />`

in the view.I forgot to provide the `@` sign before `Model.ProductTitle`. Now it's ok.

Thanks everyone.